# Transfer a Mathematica expression into a TeX format

Tags: latex

Using the Mathematica command

```
Table[BernoulliB[n,X]//TraditionalForm,{n,0,10}]
```

I get eleven polynomials which I want to write inside a TeX file with the minimal possible effort. Is there an elegant way to do this so that I can avoid to type each polynomial into the TeX file.

Comment: Use`TexForm` onto it.

Comment: `TeXForm`, to be accurate.

Comment: I wonder why this does'nt work on my computer. When I use TexForm on, sys, the Bernoulli table there is no evalluatoin

Comment: @Szabolcs Yup, a typo; of course it should be `TeXForm`.

Comment: @cyrille.piatecki Did you try as `TeXForm /@ Table[BernoulliB[n,X]//TraditionalForm,{n,0,10}]`?

Comment: @cirille.piatecki  Thanks, it works fine.

Comment: Sorry, for this so late reaction I discover slowly how se works. This works so why TxForm[... ] does not work ?

Comment: Now it works nicely Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It was already suggested in the comments to use TeXForm, but you might also like to know that within a Mathematica notebook you can highlight output with your cursor, right click, choose the option "LaTeX" under "Copy As", and then paste into your .tex file.